# viewing running processes with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, process

I want to see all the processes running on my computer but the cmd command only gives the applications, not any scripts or smaller files. I am trying to figure out a way to list all the processes in a more advanced way that will list EVERYTHING currently running. Does anyone know a way to do that with vbscript? Or if there is a better way to do this what is it?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by *"not any scripts or smaller files"*. Do you mean text files?

Answer (score 2):

**Using `TaskList` Command**

`TaskList` Command can be used to display a list of all running applications and services with their details and Process IDs(PIDs).

```
Dim ProTFPath, ProTF, StrPrInfo, StrPrInfoA, PrInfo

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

ProTFPath = "C:\PROCESSES.txt"

WshShell.Run "CMD /C TASKLIST /V /FO LIST > """ + ProTFPath + """", 0, True
' Here Run is used instead Exec to avoid console window flashes.

If FSO.FileExists(ProTFPath) Then
  Set ProTF = FSO.OpenTextFile(ProTFPath, 1, False)
End If

StrPrInfoA = ProTF.ReadAll

PrInfo = Split(StrPrInfoA, VbCrLf + VbCrLf)

For I = 0 To UBound(PrInfo)
  WScript.Echo PrInfo(I)
Next

Erase PrInfo
ProTF.Close
```

If you no longer need this file, add following lines to the end of the script:

```
If FSO.FileExists(ProTFPath) Then
  FSO.DeleteFile(ProTFPath, True)
End If
```

See more information about `TaskList` [here.](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)

Comment: I would have used wmi. Didn't know about the tasklist command. Thanks, I learnt a new thing today. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
EXE_Process = AllProcessRunningEXE(".")
Vbs_Process = AllProcessRunningVBS (".")

Function AllProcessRunningEXE( strComputerArg )
strProcessArr = ""
    Dim Process, strObject
    strObject   = "winmgmts://" & strComputerArg
    For Each Process in GetObject( strObject ).InstancesOf( "win32_process" )
        strProcessArr = strProcessArr & ";" & vbNewLine & Process.name
    Next
    AllProcessRunningEXE = Mid(strProcessArr,3,Len(strProcessArr))
End Function


Function AllProcessRunningVBS (strComputerArg)
    strProcessArr = ""
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputerArg & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'cscript.exe' OR Name = 'wscript.exe'")
    For Each objItem in colItems
        strProcessArr = strProcessArr & ";" & vbNewLine & objItem.CommandLine
    Next
    AllProcessRunningVBS = Mid(strProcessArr,3,Len(strProcessArr))

    Set objWMIService = Nothing
    Set colItems = Nothing
End Function
```